# Prove that a and b commute if and only if they are powers of the same word

Tags: formal-languages

Two words $a$ and $b$ commute if $ab=ba$.

How to demonstrate that $a$ and $b$ commute if and only if they are powers of 
the same word ?

$ab=ba \Leftrightarrow \exists \space  \tau  \in \Sigma^{*} \mid a=\tau^{k} and \space b=\tau^{k'}$

The demonstration in this direction is trivial:

$\space \exists \space  \tau  \in \Sigma^{*} \mid a=\tau^{k} and \space b=\tau^{k'} \Rightarrow ab=ba$

But I don't manage to find an elegant solution for the other direction.

Comment: This classical result is covered in any textbook or monograph on the topic of combinatorics on words.

Answer (score 4):

By induction.

> If $|a|=|b|$ then $a=b$ and we are done.
>
>  Otherwise, assume $|a|<|b|$. 
>  Then $a$ is a prefix of $b$, so there is a word $c$ such that $b = ac$.
>  Now $ab = ba$ implies $aac=aca$, or, after deleting prefix $a$, $ac=ca$. By the inductive property $a$ and $c$ are both powers of the same word $\tau$, and so is $b$.

Answer (score 3):

If $ab=ba$ then the word $w = ab$ satisfies $R^{|a|}(w) = w$, where $R$ is the right-rotation operator, and $R^{|a|}$ just applies this operator $a$ times. Since $R^{|w|}(w) = w$, [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) implies that $R^{(|a|,|w|)}(w) = w$, where $g = (|a|,|w|)$ is the greatest common divisor of $|a|$ and $|w|$. Since $g \mid |w|$, we see that $w = z^{|w|/g}$ for some word $z$ of length $g$. Since $g \mid |a|$, we see that $a = z^{|a|/g}$ and $b = z^{|b|/g}$.