# Let u and v be two strings. What about the reverse order of their concatenaited string?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, strings

let $u$ and $v$ be two strings. Is $(u.v)^R$ equals to $u^R.v^R$?

**Note:** The $R$ notation means reverse order and the $.(dot)$ notation means concatenation.

Comment: Have you tried a few strings? For example, $u=0$, $v=1$?

Comment: @Apass.Jack I have tried to prove it. But I couldn't.So I thought maybe they are not equal.

Comment: Let me rephrase my suggestion. Have you checked that equality with a few concrete instances? For example, what are $(u.v)^R$ and $u^R.v^R$ when $u$ is the string 0 and $v$ is the string 1?

Answer (score 2):

No, $(u\cdot v)^R\not=u^R\cdot v^R$ more often than not.

For example, if $u$ is the string $race$ and $v$ is the string $car$. Then  $$(u\cdot v)^R=(racecar)^R=racecar$$
while
$$u^R\cdot v^R=(race)^R(car)^R=ecarrac.$$

---

Here are a few related exercises. All variables stand for strings.

**Exercise 1**. If $u$ or $v$ is the empty word, then $(u\cdot v)^R=u^R\cdot v^R$.

**Exercise 2**. If $u$ or $v$ are words of length 1 such that $(u\cdot v)^R=u^R\cdot v^R$. Then $u=v$.

**Exercise 3**. If $u=u^R$ and $v=v^R$, can we guarantee $(u\cdot v)^R=u^R\cdot v^R$?

**Exercise 4**. Prove that $(u\cdot v)^R=v^R\cdot u^R$.

Comment: I have to use induction to prove it?

Comment: Yes, mathematically speaking. It becomes clear and obvious once you have played with several examples.

Comment: Inequality "more often than not": to be precise we have $(uv)^R = u^Rv^R$  precisely when $u$ and $v$ are [powers of the same word](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/75378)